# CSS for Disabled Textbox (Prevent "graying out" in Firefox/Chrome)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

Is it possible to set CSS for disabled textboxes? I don't want the automatic gray-out in Firefox/Chrome.

The reason is that I'm sometimes disabling textboxes right before submitting a form so they don't get unnecessarily transmitted (and clutter the URL), and that gray-out behavior is degrading the user experience by creating flicker.

Help?

Comment: Reference: [How to set different styles when textbox is enabled / disabled?](http://forums.asp.net/t/1830163.aspx?How+to+set+different+styles+when+textbox+is+enabled+disabled+)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to style the text box by defining a class with how you want it to look, and then adding the class when you disable the input.  If you're not worried about IE6 compatibility, then try using attribute selectors:

```
input[disabled="disabled"] {
     /* your CSS style */
}
```

You should be able to use any styles you'd use on any other element.